Cross region authentication
I have an web application which is deployed in two aws regions. Each application is linked to its own cognito user pool.
Application A <-> User Pool A
Application B <-> User Pool B
This application has a React frontend that uses aws-amplify ( without hosted UI ) to take care of the authentication and all that.
Now, my dilemma is, how would I be able to achieve the following scenario?
User from pool A can authenticate in Application B
User from pool B can authenticate in Application A
This to be done seamlessly, using a single set of credentials.
Would a single cognito user pool be a better approach for this scenario ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/security-cognito-regional-data-considerations.html  doesn't look like cognito can do much multi region out of the box.  I think you'll have an easier time with a single cognito pool in one region (of course if that region has issues, it might cause an outage, but that's fairly uncommon and could happen anyway)
